# SQL Join issue with query columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm new to SQL and I'm attempting to build a tool. Basically I've used a JOIN to put two different database tables into one based on matching criteria.
My issue now is once I've done this how do i tell the query to look for particular columns in each table. I only need a few from both tables but my query currently returns all due to the wildcard. Such as column STAR from FDE_XML_VIEW and localColAlt from WKS_LOG_VIEW:

```
select *
from EXCDS1.dbo.FDE_XML_VIEW join
     EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW
     on WKS_LOG_VIEW.AID = FDE_XML_VIEW.ACID
where LastUpdateMachine = 'R02' and
      LastUpdateTime > '2021-03-10 08:30:00.000' and
      LastUpdateTime < '2021-03-10 09:00:00.000';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `select` to select the columns you want.

Comment: Check out Alias's, makes joins and selecting columns easier to read

Comment: Hi Gordon I'm slightly confused as to where i put the the second table SELECT i.e. WKS_LOG_VIEW ? Can both SELECTS be run before the JOIN?

Comment: `select table1.col1, table2.col4 from table1 join table2...` and yes, learn how to use aliases

Answer (score 0):

You could use variable names(aliases) for your tables and then select your desired columns using these aliases instead of retrieving everything

**EXAMPLE**

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

Comment: thank you im slighty confused because the tables are in two different databases.

Comment: @ZZBeard if you are using two different databases you can prefix the table references with your database names. For example: `database1.table1` and `database2.table2`.